# How to write this mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have three tables tb_poll,tb_poll_answer,tb_poll_votes

**tb_poll** has    `id,question`

**tb_poll_answer** has `id,poll_id,answer`

**tb_poll_votes** has `id,poll_answer_id`

I want to select all questions and it answers(with count votes).

Finally i want to list

```
Id    Question           Answers

1     Which is....?     1.PHP(70) 2.ASP(30) 3.JSP(2)

2     ......             .......
```

How to write best mysql query here?

Comment: We generally like to see a bit of effort on the part of the asker, on Stackoverflow. Agreeing with @Neil, what have you tried yourself? Is there any specific issue with the query you're writing that you're having problems with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got result through sub query

```
 SELECT q.id,q.question,av.vt,GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(av.answer,av.vt) SEPARATOR ' ') 
 AS Answers FROM tb_poll AS q LEFT JOIN
 (SELECT a.answer,a.poll_id,COUNT(v.id) AS vt FROM tb_poll_answers AS a LEFT JOIN tb_poll_votes AS v ON a.id=v.poll_answer_id GROUP BY a.id) AS av
ON q.id=av.poll_id
GROUP BY q.id
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this query now:

```
 SELECT q.id,q.question,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(a.id,'.',a.answer,COUNT(v.id) SEPARATOR ' ')) AS `Answers`
 FROM `tb_poll` AS q
 LEFT JOIN `tb_poll_answers` AS a
  ON q.id = a.poll_id
 LEFT JOIN `tb_poll_votes` AS v
  ON a.id = v.poll_answer_id
 WHERE 1
 GROUP BY q.id
 ORDER BY q.id
```

Comment: It only returns one row and it row contains the column(Answers) concatenation of all tb_poll_answer

Comment: @w3father oops sorry, forgot the group by bit

Comment: Why are you using  WHERE 1? wt purpose here?

Comment: @ianbarker, Wouldn't you want the `CONCAT` inside the `GROUP_CONCAT`?

Comment: @ianbarker i updated my question please check,if u know query help me

Comment: Now im getting this error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SEPARATOR ' ')) AS `Answers` FROM `tb_poll` AS q LEFT JOIN `tb_poll_answers` A' at line 2

Comment: @w3father Looks like i missed a bracket, but as a learning exercise I'll let you work out where it needs to go